# Passing data to a dynamic component loader using a service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I have a dynamic component loader, and I need to pass in data through a service. I can get the data to display if I fire the function on `click` for example, but not `OnInit`.

- I have tried using AfterViewInit
- Eventually the data will be coming from an API

**Update:**
Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loader-with-service)

**app.component.html**

```
<app-answer-set></app-answer-set>
```

**header.component.html**

```
<ng-template appHeaderHost></ng-template>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() component;
  @ViewChild(HeaderHostDirective) headerHost: HeaderHostDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.headerHost.viewContainerRef;

    viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

}
```

**header-host.directive.ts**

```
export class HeaderHostDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

**header-data.service.ts**

```
export class HeaderDataService {

  private headerDataSource = new Subject<any>();
  headerData$ = this.headerDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setHeaderData(data: any) {
    this.headerDataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

**answer-set.component.html**

```
<app-header [component]="component"></app-header>
<button (click)="setHeaderData()">click</button>
```

**answer-set.component.ts**

```
export class AnswerSetComponent implements OnInit {
  component: any = AnswerSetHeaderDetailsComponent;

  constructor(private headerDataService: HeaderDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setHeaderData();
  }

  setHeaderData() {
    const data = [{name: 'Header stuff'}];
    this.headerDataService.setHeaderData(data);
  }

}
```

**answer-set-header-details.html**

```
<dt>First:</dt>
<dd>Description</dd>
<dt>Second</dt>
<dd>Description</dd>
<p>
  data will show on click of button but not <code>onInit</code>:
</p>
<p>
  {{headerData}}
</p>
```

**answer-set-header-details.component.ts**

```
export class AnswerSetHeaderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private headerDataService: HeaderDataService) { }
  headerData: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerDataService.headerData$
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.headerData = data[0].name;
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running through the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) I found that I needed to pass the data to the componentRef instance, something like this:

```
(<IHeader>componentRef.instance).data = headerItems.data;
```

After a little refactoring I ended up passing both the component and the data through a service, see the updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loader-with-service) for a working example.

Eventually I'll look to pass in multiple components, but for now this works.

**header.component.html**

```
<ng-template appHeaderHost></ng-template>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
/* ... */

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(HeaderHostDirective) headerHost: HeaderHostDirective;

  subscriptionManager = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {

    const headerConfigSubscription = this.headerService.headerConfig$
      .subscribe((headerItems: HeaderItem) => {
        this.loadComponent(headerItems);
      });

    this.subscriptionManager
      .add(headerConfigSubscription);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadComponent(headerItems: HeaderItem) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(headerItems.component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.headerHost.viewContainerRef;

    viewContainerRef.clear();

    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    (<IHeader>componentRef.instance).data = headerItems.data ? headerItems.data : null;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    /**
     * @description Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
     * to prevent memory leaks
     */
    this.subscriptionManager.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**header.service.ts**

```
/* ... */

export class HeaderService {
  private headerConfigSource = new Subject<any>();
  headerConfig$ = this.headerConfigSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  configureHeaderItems(headerItems: HeaderItem) {
    this.headerConfigSource.next(headerItems);
  }
}
```

**header.ts**

```
/* ... */

export interface IHeader {
  data: any;
}

export interface IHeaderItem {
  component: Type<any>;
  data?: any;
}

export class HeaderItem implements IHeaderItem {
  constructor(
    public component: Type<any>,
    public data?: any
  ) {
    this.component = component;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

**main.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  headerItems: HeaderItem;

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configureHeaderItems();
  }

  configureHeaderItems() {
    this.headerItems = new HeaderItem(MainHeaderDetailsComponent, {});

    this.getHeaderItemData();
  }

  /**
   * @description This is where we would make the API call and get the data
   * but we can mock it for now 
   */
  getHeaderItemData() {
    const data = {
      name: 'I am loaded dynamically!'
    };

    this.headerItems.data = data;
    this.headerService.configureHeaderItems(this.headerItems);
  }

}
```

**main.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  /* ... */

  // Need to add to entryComponents
  entryComponents: [MainHeaderDetailsComponent]
})
export class AnswerSetModule { }
```

**main-header-details.component.html**

```
<p>
  Header content. {{data.name}}
</p>
```

**main-header-details.component.ts**

```
/* ... */

export class MainHeaderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() data: any;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```